# Json schema deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, jsonserializer

I'm trying to deserialize JSON that looks like this:

```
{"METHOD":"GET_IVR_ACTION",
 "DATA":   {"DID":"972732248673",
            "CALLER_ID":"972508822570",
            "CALLER_NAME":null,
            "IVR_UNIQUE_ID":"4c80c29146c61f3c24ed434e11cb340b",
            "DTMF":"",
            "MENU":"-1",
            "PREVIOUS_MENU":"-1"}
}
```

into this class object:

```
public class DATA
{
    public string DID = string.Empty;
    public string CALLER_ID = string.Empty;
    public string CALLER_NAME = string.Empty;
    public string IVR_UNIQUE_ID = string.Empty;
    public string DTMF = string.Empty;
    public string MENU = string.Empty;
    public string PREVIOUS_MENU = string.Empty;
}
```

Using JavaScriptSerializer:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
DATA data = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<DATA>(jsonString);
```

The object remains disappointingly empty...

Comment: please try..public string DID { get; set; }..on all your properties

Answer (score 1):

Well, the JSON string has a nested object. `JavaScriptSerializer` or essentially any other JSON serialization tool uses reflection to map properties and attributes one by one.

You should first extract the `Data` string out, and then use that as parameter of `Deserialize` method.

Try to test with:

```
        {
           "DID":"972732248673",
           "CALLER_ID":"972508822570",
           "CALLER_NAME":null,
           "IVR_UNIQUE_ID":"4c80c29146c61f3c24ed434e11cb340b",
           "DTMF":"",
           "MENU":"-1",
           "PREVIOUS_MENU":"-1"
        }
```

To get the `Data` part, you have two options:

1. Use `JavaScriptDeserializer`, but assign the result to a dynamic object (not strongly typed). In this case, deserializer uses its type resolvers to find nested types and would give you complete object graph (object hierarchy)
2. Use regular expressions to get the `Data` object JSON out

Comment: Well yes, I know that the problem is the nested object... I tried it with a simple JSON as the one you wrote above.. how do I extract only the DATA string out?? THANX!!

Comment: Another alternative is to nest your DATA class within another class.

Comment: Ok, I managed to deserialize it to a dynamic object like this: var dict = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);           And now Im trying to extract the CALLER_ID from the object.                    when I try like this: dict["DATA"]["CALLER_ID"] --- I get the result as a dynamic{string} type.. how do I convert it to a simple string??

Answer (score 0):

This is my method of deserializing JSON:

```
    public static bool CreateJson(ref Dictionary<string, object> values, string source)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            object json = serializer.DeserializeObject(source);
            values = json as Dictionary<string, object>;
            result = values != null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Notice that it creates a Dictionary and returns it.  You can then (in the debugger) browse that result and look at the values in it.  Then you can figure out the right way to pull the values you want from it.  Works for me every time.

HTH!